# Can't rearrange Drag and Drop Items

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drag-and-drop, listbox

I work on Visual Studio 2019, on a WindowsForms Project.

my problem is that i just can drag and drop items upwards but if i move items downwards the program crashes.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DragDrop
    ListBox1.Items.Insert(ListBox1.IndexFromPoint(ListBox1.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))), e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text))
    ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_DragOver(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DragOver
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseDown
    ListBox1.DoDragDrop(ListBox1.Text, DragDropEffects.All)
End Sub
```

Edit: this is the error I get:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "InvalidArgument=Value with the value -1 is invalid for the index.

Answer (score 0):

Just check to make sure your index isn't at -1:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DragDrop
    Dim index As Integer = ListBox1.IndexFromPoint(ListBox1.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y)))
    If index > -1 Then
        ListBox1.Items.Insert(index, e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text))
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```